# The Bad Clue Puzzle

Tags: logical-deduction, logic-grid

[image: Logo]

> **The Jumbled**
>   **Story**

Johnny might have had a couple beers when putting this one together. What he intended was a logic puzzle of friends, their favorite classic computer system, and how they used to use it.

**Here are the clues, I think**

1. Johnny's parents are very strict and monitor his computer usage. They are very conservative.
2. Heather and Johnny don't like fruit.
3. Out of the 3 companies, Johnny wouldn't hack red or numbers.

**Puzzle Data:**
Johnny, Games, Heather, Apple, Commodore 64, BrandonJ, Hacking, Homework

Quick Puzzle I made during lunch. Good Luck with this quick one.

Comment: Is the missing clue going to be found in the deeply hidden personal data of Brandon_J?

Comment: Aren’t there only 2 companies?

Comment: There is a 3rd Classic Computer company that I thought would be infered, however, it was Texas Instruments. Maybe I am too old for you guys....ugh

Comment: Was that clued by “conservative”, @JohnS. ?

Comment: Maybe not, but there seems (to me) to be a clue missing to be able to disambiguate the puzzle here completely — rot13(fcrpvsvpnyyl nf gb ubj gb gryy OenaqbaW'f npgvivgl ncneg sebz Zvpuryyr'f). Perhaps this is intentional, as Johnny having a couple beers might have led him to mess up in his intention of creating a solvable logic puzzle; if that's the trick here, though, it's unclear what we're meant to do now. Solve it from other clues too well hidden for me to see? State that Johnny flubbed it?  Perhaps a hint is in order.